# Disadvantages to having many MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I was wondering what the disadvantages are to having many tables (let's say ~100,000) rather than one large table. An example would be having one table per user, or one large table for all users where the user_id is an index.

E.g. One of these named `stuff`:

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| x        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| y        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
|    .     |    .    |   .  |  .  |    .    |   .   |
|    .     |    .    |   .  |  .  |    .    |   .   |
|    .     |    .    |   .  |  .  |    .    |   .   |
```

vs. many of these where each is named `[user_id]_stuff`. That way I know which table to go to given a user_id.

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| x     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| y     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
|   .   |    .    |   .  |  .  |    .    |   .   |
|   .   |    .    |   .  |  .  |    .    |   .   |
|   .   |    .    |   .  |  .  |    .    |   .   |
```

My gut is telling me that having many tables will run faster, but having one table will be more maintainable/robust.

Also, would there be security issues because the user's id is being concatenated to make the table name? Though I guess it would be easy to check if the id supplied is a number.

Comment: what does a query on 100k tables look like?

Comment: Your violating the principles of normalization by having one table for each user. I would urge you to read up on normalization. Databases are  designed to deal with *a lot* of data.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Not intending to be pedantic, but FYI such a design actually would not violate any normalization principle - it violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).

Comment: @eggyal My comment was more intended to reflect the the relational principles it's supposed to reinforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My gut is telling me that having many tables will run faster, but having one table will be more maintainable/robust.

Many identically-structured tables would be contrary to the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).

**Don't do it**.  At least not without *very* good reason—with suitable indexes, millions of records per table is easily enough for MySQL to handle without any need for partitioning; and even if one *did* need to partition the data, there are [better ways](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) than this manual kludge (which can give rise to ambiguous, potentially inconsistent data and lead to redundancy and complexity in your data manipulation code).  Not to mention that, in MySQL, [joins are limited to a maximum of 61 tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/joins-limits.html).

Instead, the single table approach is *the correct solution* to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It felt like it was wrong, so I'm glad I have some more information on it.